# Bounded set & outer measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu: P(\mathbb R) \rightarrow [0, \infty]$.

$\mu(A)$ is $0$, if $A$ is bounded, $1$ if $A$ is not bounded.

Is this $\mu$ an outer measure?

($\mu(\emptyset) = 0$ is clear, but what about the subadditivity and monotonity? )

Comment: Can you show your attempt please?

Comment: Yeah, I think it is an outer measure, because $\mu$ is monotone (takes only value 0 or 1) and also subadditive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not an outer measure.

Take $A_n=[-n,n]$

Then $1=\mu^*(\Bbb{R})=\mu^*(\bigcup_nA_n)>0=\sum_n \mu^*(A_n)$

Comment: Thanl you very much for this answer! What about the following correction: $\mu(A)$ is 0, if $A$ is empty, $\mu(A)$ is 1, if $A$ is non-empty and bounded and $\mu(A) = \infty$ if $A$ is unbounded. This should be an outer measure, right?

Comment: @StMan  then that  is an outer measure...